# MVC Routing info needed on client?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need routing info for my javascript logic on the client. I have a workable solution right now but it feels kind of clunky. I am injecting a hidden field on the page. I'm thinking there has to be a better way. This is what i'm currently doing:

```
<input type="hidden" id="rt" value="@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",Request.Url.Scheme,Request.Url.Authority,Url.Content("~"))"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, very clunky. Actually you don't need absolute urls for your javascript. It can work with relative urls. For example:

```
@Html.Hidden("rt", Url.Content("~/"))
```

Now whether using a hidden field is a good thing or not is though to say without knowing more details about your scenario and what exactly you are trying to do in javascript. But let's consider a very common scenario. You want to AJAXify a form. In this case you would use HTML helpers in your view to generate the form and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: do something with the results
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

See how we no longer need any hardcoded urls or hidden fields fore the javascript.

Or let's consider another scenario. You want to AJAXify an anchor. Same thing. You use `Html.ActionLink` to generate your anchor and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $.get(this.href, function(result) {
            // TODO: do something with the results
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or yet another scenario. You have some div container that you want to send an AJAX request to some controller action upon clicking on it. In this case you could use HTML5 data-* attributes on the div:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-url="@Url.Action("Foo", "Home")">Some contents</div>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mydiv').click(function() {
        $.get($(this).data('url'), function(result) {
            // TODO: do something with the results
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

OK, now you see that you no longer need any hidden fields. There are always possibilities to do better.

Comment: Thanks Darin for the reply. I was trying to eliminate the hidden field though. Injecting a hidden field on the page is the only way?

Comment: @user127954, no, you don't need hidden fields. There are better ways. It will just depend on what you are trying to do on the client side.

Comment: Pretty much i'm just using it in my javascript for the base url of my site so when it changes i don't have to change my javascript (don't want to hard code urls).

Comment: @user127954, as I said, your javascript doesn't need absolute url and as I said there are better ways. It will just depend on where and how you need it. You say that you are using it in your javascript for base url but the question is where you need it? I've shown you on my answer different scenarios where you actually don't ever need such base urlin your javascript. You simply unobtrusively enhance some already existing DOM element which is already containing the correct url generated on the server using url helpers, so that if your routes change your javascript won't break.